# sql query with extra relation rows or null

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have
accounts (id, name)
deals (id, name, account_id) many to one accounts
pos (id, name, deal_id) many to one deals

I want to have an export that has all accounts, deals and pos.

- Not all deals have a po so if I from POs then I will miss some deals.
- If I from deals I will only get 0 or 1 PO even if there is 2 or more.  I might also miss some accounts because not all accounts have deals.
- All pos have a deal,  all deals have an account.

I believe I need to do a seperate report for each where it doesnt have relation and then union each together.  I dont quite have the syntax correct.

table could be

```
account_name  | deal_name    | po_name
cool account  | null         | null
another       | sweet deal   | null
another       | bitter sweet | null
last for best | deal 1       | po here
last for best | deal 1       | another po
last for best | deal 2       | null
last for best | deal 3       | o yea
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `left joins` from `accounts` to `deals` and finally `pos`:

```
select
  a.name account_name,
  d.name deal_name,
  p.name po_name
from accounts a
left join deals d on d.account_id = a.id
left join pos p on p.deal_id = d.id
```

Comment: Dont know why I forgot that is how that worked this way.  thank you